# How can I remove UK keyboard layout from languages list

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-languages

After update I got UK keyboard added to my list. Can't remove it.

I tried

1)[Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/cant-remove-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10/058acf33-16d9-47f4-a24b-245b8823d90e)

2) and regedit IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout

None above worked

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have English (UK) installed.

Any language pack also installs the most typical keyboard layout for said language.

In order to remove the default keyboard you need to add the correct one you're using to that LP first. Once you have more than one keyboard set, the default one can be removed.

Answer (score -1):

On Region and Language interface, click English (United States), Options.

If you can see "US Keyboard" there, remove it, restart.

If you can’t see it, click Add a keyboard, add "US keyboard", then remove that keyboard, restart.